# How to reshape input data correctly for input in CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN model, which input image size is `(150, 150)`. I want to feed array-like data for `predict` function (tensorflow) like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1.5, 1.5))
plt.plot(time_values, signal_values, '-o', c='r')
plt.axis('off')
fig.canvas.draw()
data = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
```

And when I try:

```
CNN_model.predict(data)
```

I get an error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 150, 150, 3) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 150, 150, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 150, 3).
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Why my shape is `(None, 150, 3)`, but not `(None, 150, 150, 3)`?

Comment: In the last line, just directly write `data.reshape((1, 150, 150, 3))`

Comment: @SreekantShenoy thank you a lot. As I understood, the firtst value here (None, 150, 150, 3) is equal to ((1, 150, 150, 3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new dimension to your array `data`:

```py
data = data[None, :]
```

Its shape will then be `(1, 150, 150, 3)`, as expected by tensorflow.